# Is it possible to add multiple event handlers to ServerClick in an .aspx page?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have an aspx page with two custom buttons that looks like this:

```
<cfw:Button runat="server" OnServerClick="CreateProduct" name="Create product" />
<cfw:Button runat="server" OnServerClick="OrderProduct" name="Order product" />
```

I want 1 button that creates and orders the product at the same time. So I basically want to ask **can I add multiple event handlers in the .aspx to the same event?**

The button event itself supports this and it is programatically possible:

```
    public event ProcessEventHandler ServerClick
    {
        add
        {
            Events.AddHandler(serverClick, value);
            PostBack = true;
        }
        remove { Events.RemoveHandler(serverClick, value); }
    }
```

Rules of the game (because of internal / company standards):

- I **can't** use stuff like **<% %>**
- I'm **not allowed** to add **Code Behind / Code** beside to the page
- I might need to be able to add 4 event handlers, so don't come with solutions like SecondOnServerClick (<strike>I will vote you down ;-)</strike> )

I'm looking forward to your input!

Comment: Threatening to downvote those who try to help you isn't going to encourage responses. What if `SecondOnServerClick`, `ThirdOnServerClick` etc happen to be the only viable solution once your other constraints are taken into consideration?

Comment: @LukeH Hahaha... hence the ;-). Well... actually in that case the only valid answer would be "no". I'll rephrase the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well here is my solution: Based on your constraints, it seems the only possibility is to either (a) inherit your custom framework button and create a subclass, or (b) modify the existing framework button.

Here is an implementation which works well ( I tested it :) ) by subclassing the System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button class, and test page:

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
namespace StackOverflowWeb
{
    public class MultiCastButton : Button
    {
        public ListItemCollection ClickEventList { get; set; }

        private void SetEventHandlers()
        {
            // convert listitem values to EventHandler type
            Func<ListItem, EventHandler> getEventHandler = ev =>
                EventHandler.CreateDelegate(
                    typeof(EventHandler), this.Page, ev.Value) as EventHandler;

            if (ClickEventList != null && ClickEventList.Count > 0)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < ClickEventList.Count; i++)
                { 
                    this.Click += getEventHandler(ClickEventList[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);

            // must occur OnInit because 'this.Page' 
            // is null prior to this event firing
            SetEventHandlers();        
       }
    }
}
```

Then, you have the test page (codebehind) - I know you said you don't have codebehind, so these event handlers can live in any class or class library, and you can register that class on the front of the page. This solution works in an isolated test environment (i.e., new ASP.net web project).

You might have to modify the code in the getEventHandler() method, instead of the target type being this.Page, you may use whatever type contains your actual event handler voids.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public void Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs args) 
    { 
        ResultPanel.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Test Click Executed" }); 
    }
    public void Test_Click2(object sender, EventArgs args) 
    { 
        ResultPanel.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Test Click 2 Executed" }); 
    }
    public void Test_Click3(object sender, EventArgs args) 
    { 
        ResultPanel.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Test Click 3 Executed" }); 
    }
    public void Test_Click4(object sender, EventArgs args) 
    { 
        ResultPanel.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Test Click 4 Executed" }); 
    }
}
```

And finally your declaration on the front

```
<%@ Register Namespace="StackOverflowWeb" TagPrefix="sow" Assembly="StackOverflowWeb" %>
<style> span { display: block; }</style>

<sow:MultiCastButton runat="server" ID="TestClickMultiCastButton" >
    <ClickEventList>
        <asp:ListItem>Test_Click</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Test_Click2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Test_Click3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Test_Click4</asp:ListItem>
    </ClickEventList>
</sow:MultiCastButton>

<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="ResultPanel" />
```

Note that I am using ListItem and a ListItemCollection because it lends itself most easily to being declared in the UI of an ASP.net web forms application.

I hope you find this useful! It is my first answer here on StackOverflow, although I have been an avid reader for a long time.

Comment: Awesome I hope it does the trick. Let me know if you run into any issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've no way to add more than a handler in design time.

If you can't use server code in the page - which is a very bad design principle -, I'd point that you have no options.

By the way, if I understood you well, you've a custom button control with your own event accessors defined, as you shown in the question.

I only see one solution.

You can add a new property called OnServerClick which is of type of string and change current ServerClick event accessor to another identifier.

Now OnServerClick is a comma-separated list of server event handlers, and during the Init, you can bind these handlers to the event.

You can achieve that and you can have what you want.

I hope you're not going to vote down no one ;) We're here to support others.

Comment: @Matías I was hoping .Net would support something like <cfw:Button runat="server" OnServerClick="CreateProduct" OnServerClick="OrderProduct" name="Create and order product" />

Comment: "if you can't use server code in the page", that's due to the use of a framework. The framework should take care of stuff like getting you the right objects and the implementors (different bunch of people) build the aspx pages; mostly elements / html / css.

Comment: I see, right, but you don't have that support and can you clarify if this is a custom button or the out-of-the-box one?

Comment: This button is one of our own framework, but it could be tested with an asp:Button as well, because that button uses the same ServerClick event handler (long live Reflector).

Comment: And can't you extend, modify that button, can you? Maybe you can inherit it and call it MulticastButton having a MulticastServerClick?

Comment: In case of the MulticastServerClick, I'll need to add some sort of custom event binding in my button with splits or something? Because there is no native asp.net support for this?

Comment: Right! This is the way of doing it. In fact, "OnWhateverEvent" does this job. It's a string property and in its setter, you'll have code to get the method as delegate for the whole event.